# Making Printer default Duplex from Command prompt - Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to make a network printer default duplex from DOS batch file. I am using the following command from Batch file to execute it from Powershell. My printer has windows default driver HP Universal PCL 6.

The command executes, but nothing happens.

```
@Echo off

powershell -command "& {Set-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName \"Ban-Cox - HP M4015 - Corner B\" -DuplexingMode TwoSidedLongEdge}"
```

What will fix this?

Comment: @Priya clutter things like thanks, hi, signature [should be removed, not added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/230282)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)